Inaccessible cardinal in standard transitive models of ZFC
For a standard model of ZFC $\langle N,\in \rangle$ (where $N$ is a transitive set), if $\kappa\in N$ is an inaccessible cardinal in the model, does it imply that it is an inaccessible cardinal (in general, in the universe) ?
Id est, if for $\kappa\in N$, we have $\langle N,\in\rangle\models SI(\kappa)$, then $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal.
(Where SI(x) is the formula saying that x is an inaccessible cardinal).
Is it true ? If yes, how to show it ?

No. If there is any transitive model containing inaccessibles, there will be (by using Lowenheim-Skolem to get a countable elementary submodel and then Mostowski collapsing it) a countable transitive model that is elementarily equivalent, hence contains ordinals that it believes are inaccessible cardinals. And since it has a countable height, none of the ordinals in that model are actually inaccessible. Note this works with literally any (first-order expressible) large cardinal property.

Thanks a lot ! But then, how would you show that the consistency of $ZFC$ implies the consistency of $ZFC + \neg \exists \kappa SI(\kappa)$ ? I am trying to prove it, I thought you suppose the existence of a model of $ZFC$ $\langle N,\in \rangle$ that satisfies $\exists \kappa SI(\kappa)$ wlog, you take the smallest such $\kappa\in N$, and then you show that $V_{\kappa}\models \neg \exists \kappa SI(\kappa)$. But then it doesn't make really sense if $\kappa$ is not a "real" inaccessible cardinal.

@MamounAich Models of the form $V_\alpha$ have some rather special properties not shared by all transitive models. An inaccessible cardinal in such a model is really inaccessible. Try to prove it directly.

@MamounAich That's the right idea, but you consider $V_\kappa^N$, the submodel of $N$ consisting of those elements which $N$ thinks have rank $<\kappa$.

@MamounAich Sorry, I didn't read your comment closely and mistook your problem for a different one... what Alex said... then use the fact that I mentioned, relativized to $N$ to show that $V_\kappa\cap N$ must not contain anything it thinks is an inaccessible cardinal, since it doesn't contain any inaccessible cardinals (all relative to $N$). Also, though it might reasonably be considered implied, I should have mentioned above that $V_\alpha$ needs to be a model of ZFC for that to be true in general.

@MamounAich FWIW, the way I usually think about it is that if ZFC proved there were inaccessibles, then every $V_\kappa$ for $\kappa$ inaccessible would have to contain inaccessibles (since they're all models of ZFC and innaccesibles are the same in a $V_\kappa$ and the universe)... but clearly that's not the case for the least inaccessible $\kappa$. (Or you can just lean on the incompleteness theorem.)

Ok, so what you're saying is that there is NO transitive model of $ZFC$ that contains a "real" inaccessible cardinal AT ALL ? and then you use this fact and the absoluteness of SI(x) in $V_{\alpha}$ to show that there is no element in $N\cap V_{\kappa}$ that this model thinks is inaccessible cardinal. But what is $\kappa$ here exactly ? Is it an inaccessible card in $N$ (so it's not necessarily a "real" inaccessible card) ?

@MamounAich No. There can be transitive models that contain real inaccessibles (e.g. $V_\lambda$ for the second least inaccessible cardinal $\lambda$). I'm not sure where you're getting that assertion from. We just use the fact that (relativized to $N$ if applicable) $V_\kappa$ for the least inaccessible $\kappa$ doesn't contain any inaccessibles, real or imagined by it.

Ok, but $\kappa$ here is still the least inaccessible cardinal imagined by $N$ right ?

Yes. Let me flesh out that one in a little more detail: Here, $N$ doesn't even need to be transitive/well-founded, just any old model of ZFC + inaccessibles. Let $\kappa$ be the least inaccessible according to that model. Then the submodel $V_\kappa^N$ (the thing $N$ thinks is $V_\kappa$) is a model of ZFC + no inaccessibles. We can first most easily see that $N$ believes $V_\kappa^N$ to have those properties, and then make an absoluteness argument that shows it really is the case.

Ok that's more clear, thank you. I am not familiar with the noation $V_{\kappa}^N$, what does it mean formally ?

@MamounAich ${x\in N: N\models \operatorname{rank}(x)< \kappa}.$ In general if you have some set definable in ZFC you can just apply that definition in any model of ZFC to get the set the model "thinks" is that set. (i.e. ZFC proves $\exists ! x\varphi(x)$... so in the model $N$ there is a unique $x\in N$ such that $N\models \varphi(x)$).

@MamounAich (BTW I don't like that approach with an arbitrary model as much as the one I mentioned above since it is actually kind of subtle to think about the internal model theory inside non-well-founded models and get comfortable with the absoluteness argument. Though every potential issue works out in your favor in this case.)

Do you think the following equivalence is true ? $ZFC\vdash (\phi)^{V_{\alpha}}$ if and only if $\langle V_{\alpha}, \in\rangle\models \phi$, for $\phi$ a formula in set theory, $\alpha$ an ordinal

@MamounAich Not sure how to parse that. Do you mean ZFC proves (xxxx iff yyyyy) or (ZFC proves xxxx ) iff (yyyyy)?

The second one.

@MamounAich I don't know what it means for $ZFC\vdash \phi^{V_\alpha}$ for "some ordinal" $\alpha$... you can only talk about ZFC proving sentences/formulas in the language of set theory... not with parameters. If $\alpha$ is definable in set theory so that part does make sense, then it's false, since in general there will be formulas ZFC cannot decide $(\phi)^{V_\alpha}$ for but every $\phi$ will be either true or false in $V_\alpha.$

I thought that you could characterize $V_0$ with the non-closed formula $\neg x=x$, and then define recursively a formula with one free variable that  characterize $V_{\alpha}$ for each ordinal $\alpha$. Does it make sense ? and with this conception, is the equivalence at least true for $\phi$ in $ZFC$ ?

@MamounAich Sure can define the class function $\alpha\mapsto V_\alpha$ in ZFC. But that doesn't mean you can define $V_\alpha$ in ZFC for any $\alpha$ (there are too many $\alpha$'s and too few definitions, to start). If you just talk about one arbitrary $\alpha,$ it's a parameter.
